# React - File selector component that can manage VERY large file count selections

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file, upload

I'm looking for a component that can get a list of files from the user. It just needs to get the files, not upload. The uploading process is already implemented, it just needs a list of files. The component needs to fulfill the following requirements:

- Restrictable to *only* directory selection
- Supports drag and drop on top of selection via the file dialogue
- Captures all selected files in a single callback, meaning just a single state update

  - The file list should also be accessible before uploading so that they can be used in a preview
- Returns the `webkitRelativePath` for all files

The closest I've gotten to achieving this is with [Antd's](https://4x.ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-drag) `Upload` component. The limitation here was that the only way to capture the file list is with its `onChange` callback, which gets called once for *every* selected file. This means if a user is selecting thousands of files, which is a regular circumstance in my case, it will update the file list state thousands of times, causing thousands of rerenders and ultimately crashing the site.

```
const uploadProps = {
    accept: '*',
    multiple: true,
    customRequest: () => {},
    onRemove: (file: UploadFile) => {
        const index = props.fileList.indexOf(file)
        const newFileList = [...props.fileList]
        newFileList.splice(index, 1)
        props.setFileList(newFileList)
    },
    beforeUpload: () => {
        return false
    },
    onChange: (info: UploadChangeParam<UploadFile<any>>) => {
        if (JSON.stringify(info.fileList) !== JSON.stringify(props.fileList)) {
            console.log(info.fileList)
            props.setFileList(info.fileList)
        }
        if (info.fileList.length === 0 && props.progress !== 0) props.setProgress(0)
    },
    directory: true
}
<Dragger
    {...uploadProps}
    fileList={props.fileList.slice(fileListIndex, fileListIndex + 10)}
>
    <p className='ant-upload-text'>
        <b>Uploading to:</b> {S3_BUCKET.split('/').slice(1).join('/')}
    </p>
    <br></br>
    <p className='ant-upload-drag-icon'>
        <InboxOutlined />
    </p>
    <p className='ant-upload-text'>
        Browse or drag folder to upload
        <br />
        <strong>Uploading {props.fileList.length} files</strong>
        <br />
        Showing files {props.fileList.length ? fileListIndex + 1 : 0}-
        {Math.min(fileListIndex + 10, props.fileList.length)}
    </p>
</Dragger>
```

I tried a couple other libraries, but the second closest I've gotten was with the [@rpldy/uploady](https://react-uploady.org/docs/api/) library. I wrapped Antd's `Dragger` component to utilize its visual aspects with rpldy's `Uploady` and `UploadDropZone` components for the functional aspects. The Dropzone component fulfills the first three criteria, however it does not return the `webkitRelativePath` of the files in the file list.

```
<Uploady autoUpload={false} accept={'*'} webkitdirectory>
    <UploadDropZone
        onDragOverClassName='drag-over'
        htmlDirContentParams={{ recursive: true }}
        dropHandler={async (e, getFiles) => {
            let fileList = await getFiles()
            props.setFileList(fileList)
            fileList.map((file) => console.log(file.webkitRelativePath)) // Empty log
            return fileList
        }}
    >
        <Dragger
            openFileDialogOnClick={false}
            customRequest={() => {}}
            onRemove={(file: UploadFile) => {
                const index = props.fileList.indexOf(file as unknown as File)
                const newFileList = [...props.fileList]
                newFileList.splice(index, 1)
                props.setFileList(newFileList)
            }}
            fileList={
                props.fileList.slice(
                    fileListIndex,
                    fileListIndex + 10
                ) as unknown as UploadFile[]
            }
        >
            <p className='ant-upload-text'>
                <b>Uploading to:</b> {S3_BUCKET.split('/').slice(1).join('/')}
            </p>
            <br></br>
            <p className='ant-upload-drag-icon'>
                <InboxOutlined />
            </p>
            <p className='ant-upload-text'>
                <>
                    Browse or drag folder to upload
                    <br />
                    <UploadButton text='Browse' />
                    <br />
                    <strong>Uploading {props.fileList.length} files</strong>
                    <br />
                    Showing files{' '}
                    {props.fileList.length
                        ? fileListIndex + 1 > props.fileList.length
                            ? setFileListIndex(fileListIndex - 10)
                            : fileListIndex + 1
                        : 0}
                    -{Math.min(fileListIndex + 10, props.fileList.length)}
                </>
            </p>
        </Dragger>
    </UploadDropZone>
</Uploady>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is due to browser implementation decisions.

I re-created a simple version of your solution in this code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-uploady-dnd-recursive-with-full-path-2znrl6).

In Firefox, I get the path as expected while in Chrome, the path is empty as you reported.

The MDN definition for the [webkitRelativePath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/webkitRelativePath) property is: "the file's path relative to the directory selected by the user in an  element with its webkitdirectory attribute set. "

So it means it should **only** be available when actually using the file-selection dialog when the webkitdirectory

**However**, you're in luck, as I've faced this before and built in the capability to retain the path in the file name. You can activate this by passing: *withFullPath* to the [html-dir-content](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dir-content) package used by Rpldy's upload-drop-zone:

```js
htmlDirContentParams={{ recursive: true, withFullPath: true }}
```

The resulting file data will look like this:

[image]

Comment: This is great. Is there any way to make it so that it does not include the original directory in the path? So in your example, it would just be `child-b/child-b-file2.p4`. It's not a huge issue but it would simplify some things.

Comment: currently no. I will look into adding a flag for that, as to not break existing functionality. In the meantime, I would suggest removing it from the path (preferably on the server side)

Comment: I have one more question. I thought I could use Uploady's `UploadButton` the same way as I am the `UploadDropZone`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to capture the selected file list from it. I can't find any other libraries that fit my requirements. Would you happen to have any suggestions?